# How to delimit when writing with $$something$$?

Tags: delimiters, grouping

I'm writing a mathematical (linear optimization) problem in Latex and I'm having trouble delimiting all the lines (I'm using `$$something$$`) so that the formulation looks balanced.

[image]

which I've written like:

```
$$\text{Minimize} \quad V_m(w,lh)=T(wl_{(bottom)}+2lh_{(sides)}+2wh) \quad \text{(tavoitefunktio)}$$<br>
$$\text{subject to} \quad 
\begin{cases}
    lwh=V \\
    h=H\\
    l \geq 0\\
    w \geq 0\\
\end{cases} \text{(rajoitteet)}$$<br>
$$\text{suunnittelumuuttujat} \: w,l \text{ ja } h.$$.
```

What should I do to get every line (Minimize, subject to, suunnittelumuuttujat) to start from the same position?

Comment: You shouldn't use `$$`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to. And check the documentation of amsmath for multiline math environments.

Comment: Of course Ulrike means the `multline` (no "i") environment ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow - Actually, I think Ulrike was making a generic reference to `amsmath`'s multiline math environments -- one of which, it so happens, is called `multline`. :-)

Comment: @Mico, of course. Missed the "s" in environments ;) Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with an `alignat` environment. Incidentally, asking for a new line in the `cases`  environment is done with a double backslash, not a single one. Also, the indices in the first row are text, hence they should be introduced by the `\text` command, otherwise you have `math italic` (not even text italic), with math spacing between letters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}%

 \begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & \textrm{Minimize} & & V_m(w,lh)=T(wl_\textrm{(bottom)}+2lh_\textrm{(sides)}+2wh) \quad \textrm{(tavoitefunktio)}\\[1ex]
 & \textrm{subject to} \quad & & \begin{cases} lwh=V \\ h=H\\ l \geq 0\\ w \geq 0 \end{cases} \text{(rajoitteet)}\\
 & \rlap{uunnittelumuuttujat : $ w,l $ ja $ h $.} \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use \text for the indices, as \text follows the surrounding text font. I would use \mathrm.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: That's right.But is the spacing in `mathrm` the same as in `\textrm`? I never knew.

Comment: the space *should* be the same in both `\mathrm` and `\textrm`, but you can avoid that by using `\textnormal` (see [Command for text in math mode that does not become italicized inside theorem statements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14918/579))

Comment: `\textrm` also does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're loading the `amsmath` package (based on the use of the `cases` environment and the `\text` macro), I suggest you use a `gather*` environment and a couple of `\intertext` directives to structure the material. To pretty-print the material to the right of the curly brace, I further suggest you use an `array` environment instead of a `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document} 

Minimize 
\begin{gather*} 
V_m(w,lh)=T\bigl(wl_{\textrm{(bottom)}}+2lh_{\textrm{(sides)}}+2wh\bigr) \quad \text{(tavoitefunktio)}\\
\intertext{subject to}
\left\{ \begin{array}{r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l}
    lwh &  = & V \\
    h   &  = & H\\
    l   &\geq& 0\\
    w   &\geq& 0\\
\end{array} \right. 
\quad\text{(rajoitteet)}\\
\intertext{and}
\text{suunnittelumuuttujat} \quad w,l \text{ ja } h.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `align` environment

```
\begin{align}
& \text{Minimize} \quad V_m(w,lh)=T(wl_\textrm{(bottom)}+2lh_\textrm{(sides)} \quad \text{(tavoitefunktio)}
&\text{subject to} \quad \begin{cases} lwh=V \ h=H\ l \geq 0\ w \geq 0\ \end{cases} \text{(rajoitteet)}$$
&\text{suunnittelumuuttujat} : w,l \text{ ja } h.
\end{align}
```

If you want to remove the equation numbers use the `align*` environment. Note that the lines are aligned to the `&`, so you can play with that if you want.

Cheers

Comment: True. Already corrected.